# No known conversion from QList<QVariant> to QList<bool>

Tags: c++, qt

I have stuck with simple problem and can not find solution.
I want to convert `QList<QVariant>` to `QList<bool>`.

```
QList<QVariant> listVariants;
listVariants << QVariant(true) << QVariant(false) << QVariant(true);

QList<bool> listBools;
listBools = listVariants;
```

Is this possible to do it with 1 line or cast somehow from `QList<QVariant>` to `QList<booL>` or I should iterate over the `QList<QVariant>` and call `.toBool()` method on each element and then add it in the `QList<bool>`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you must iterate over the QList<QVariant>..

Comment: I think `std::transform(listVariants.begin(), listVariants.end(), std::back_inserter(listBools), [](const auto& variant) { return variant.toBool(); });` is the most straightforward way.

Comment: yes, please post it as answer so i can mark it as answered.